# ¿Cómo modifico solamente el último campo de un CSV con Sed?

Tags: linux, regex, ubuntu, sed, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo el siguiente dataset contenido en un archivo .csv:

```
PassengerId;Survived;Pclass;Name;Sex;Age;SibSp;Parch;Ticket;Fare;Cabin;Embarked
431;Yes;1;Erick;male;28.0;0;0;110564;26.5;C52;S
664;No;3;Coleff;male;36.0;0;0;349210;74.958;;S
44;Yes;2;Laroche;female;3.0;1;2;SC/Paris 2123;415.792;C
```

Ver imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero reemplazar usando `sed` los valores contenidos en la columna `Embarked` de la siguiente forma:

```
C:Cherbourg
S:Southampton
Q:Queenstown
```

He realizado lo siguiente:

```
cat titanic-passengers.csv | sed 's/C/Cherbourg/g' | sed 's/S/Southampton/g' | sed 's/Q/Queenstown/g'
```

Sin embargo, como hay otros carácteres C,S o Q en otras columnas. También efectua el cambio en ellas pero solo quiero cambiar el valor en la columna `Embarked`.

La salida esperada seria:

```
PassengerId;Survived;Pclass;Name;Sex;Age;SibSp;Parch;Ticket;Fare;Cabin;Embarked
    431;Yes;1;Erick;male;28.0;0;0;110564;26.5;C52;Southampton
    664;No;3;Coleff;male;36.0;0;0;349210;74.958;;Southampton
    44;Yes;2;Laroche;female;3.0;1;2;SC/Paris 2123;415.792;Cherbourg
```

Comment: vale. ¿Y no sería mejor con Awk? Así puedes leer el fichero de especificaciones primero y hacer la sustitución programáticamente en el segundo. En cualquier caso, la clave aquí es detectar la "C" o "S" a final de línea, que debes hacer con `C$`--> `sed 's/C$/Cherbourg/' fichero`.

Comment: Si pero en el ejercicio en particular te obligan a usar sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que te modifique solamente la última columna, debes indicárselo. Por ejemplo, diciendo que el carácter va seguido por el final de línea:

```
sed 's/C$/Cherbourg/' fichero
```

Puedes hacer varias sustituciones juntas con:

```
sed -e 's/C$/Cherbourg/' -e 's/S$/Southampton/' -e 's/Q$/Queenstown/' fichero
```

Comment: no funciona. Me devuelve el archivo sin realizar ningún cambio.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que la salida es idéntica a como es el fichero originalmente? Si el fichero es tal y como has indicado en tu pregunta, debería hacer el cambio. Si no lo hace es que hay algún carácter por allí que "molesta" y lo impide, pero para ello debería ver el archivo original.

Comment: he añadido una imagen del dataset para que lo veas. Gracias.

Comment: @Panri93 es raro, parece correcto. Lo mismo con `cat -vet fichero` puedes ver si hay algún carácter antes del final de línea.

Comment: Parece que en todas las líneas al final aparece ^M$. Por ejemplo: S^M$. A qué se refiere?

Comment: @Panri93 son ficheros realizados en Windows o DOS. Puedes convertirlos a algo apto para Unix con el comando `dos2unix`.

Comment: ahora si! era el formato.